# Kubernetes multi-clusters pod peering on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, vpc, azure-aks, vnet

How to configure routing between Pods on multiple Azure Kubernetes clusters?

Something similar to `ip-alias/vpc-native` on Google Cloud

Comment: Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it :)

Comment: Just tried this approach works as expected, but I had to do the network segmentation myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AKS, I think you can create the AKS clusters in the different subnets in the same vnet with an advanced network. For more details about the network, see [Choose the appropriate network model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-network). But it's not a perfect solution and there are some limitations for it. For example, the AKS clusters should be in the same region as the vnet.

You can take a look at [Gotchas & Solutions Running a Distributed System Across Kubernetes Clusters](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/experience-report-running-across-multiple-kubernetes-clusters/). As it said, it's hard to communicate from different regions and nothing has yet solved the problem of running a distributed system that spans multiple clusters. It’s still a very hard experience that isn’t really documented.

So, maybe there would be a long time to wait for the perfect solution.